# Linux Check Image Exists at Apache URL

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, apache-httpd

I'm writing a program that uses a Linux command to check if a file
exists on the local server.

The program executes a command with a supplied argument

```
ls *ARG_GOES_HERE* &> /dev/null
```

and then checks the status if it was able to find the file or not.

The problem is that sometimes the file is not a straight
forward path like

```
/var/www/html/images/myImage.jpg
```

Sometimes the image location is stored using the web location

```
http://192.168.1.2/images/myImage.jpg
```

Which fails in the linux command.

Is it possible to check if an image exists on a local apache
location using bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/) command to check that the file exists and can be accessed via HTTP. Something like this should work for you:

```
path_to_file=images/myImage.jpg
if curl --head --location --silent --fail "http://192.168.1.2/$path_to_file" > /dev/null
then
    printf "%s exists\n" "$path_to_file"
else
    printf "%s does not exist\n" "$path_to_file"
fi
```

The following `curl` options are used:

- `--head` – only fetch the HTTP headers (there’s no need for the body)
- `--location` – follow any HTTP redirects
- `--silent` – don’t show progress meter or error messages
- `--fail` – the `curl` commands fails with an error status if the HTTP request fails, e.g., if the web server responded with a 404, the `curl` commands exits with a status of 22 (error) instead of 0 (success).

Comment: I never thought of using curl, it seems to work perfectly